# Template member default initialization

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, default-value

Suppose I have got the following template

```
template <typename T>
class{
   T t;
};
```

Now, I want to add a constructor that initializes t with the default value for its type. That is, for numerical types, t should be initialized with `0`, for pointers, t should be initialized with `nullptr`. Finally, there could be other types like structs. Here, a good initialization would be the default constructor (which is invoked anyway, so I do not have to do anything here).

In conlusion I am looking for something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class X{
    T t;
    X() : t(default_value<T>::value);
}
```

As my imaginary syntax points out, I think it could be possible with some kind of template with different specializations which carry the default values. But how to handles structs and classes? Since I have specified `t(...)`, the default constructor is no longer an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just do

```
X() : t() { }
```

And/or this in C++11

```
X() : t { } { } // see Johannes Schaub's comments about this
```

That will value initialise (or is it default initialisation?) `t` to whatever the default value is for its type, be it 0 for built-in's, a series of (value?default) initialisations for arrays, or using the default constructor for user-defined types.

Comment: using {} is IMO not a good idea if you want to have a specific initialization (in this case you want value initialization). for example with {} now you silently have undefined behavior if T is a reference type.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb ah ok, thanks, I had no idea about that.

Comment: is X() : t() {} the same as the default constructor implicitely defined by the compiler if none is explicitly defined?